Is there a Dirichlet form on product space?
Let $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Markov process on a locally compact Polish space $E$ (say for example the Sierpinski Gasket). Then there is a Dirichlet form associated with $X_t$ on $E$, call it $({\cal E},{\cal F})$ with respect to some measure $\mu$ on $E$, where ${\cal F}$ is the domain of ${\cal E}$. Then it will admit a generator on $L^2(E,m)$, call it $A$.
$\textbf{My question}$ is, what is the setup in Dirichlet forms if I am considering the two independent and identical Markov processes generated by $A$? Call them $X,Y$. That is, to set up a Dirichlet form for $\overline{Z}_t = (X_t,Y_t)_{t\ge 0}$ on $E\times E$. We can assume they admit a heat kernel, that is, $\mathbb{P}_x(X_t \in dy) = p_t(x,y)m(dy)$ for $x,y \in E$. Same for the process $Y_t$.
$\textbf{My understanding}$ is, if we want to talk about the process $\overline{Z}_t = (X_t,Y_t)_{t\ge 0}$ on $E\times E$, we can look at the transition density of $\overline{Z}_t$, which is given by
$$
\mathbb{P}_{(x,y)}(\overline{Z}_t \in (dx',dy')) = p_t(x,x')p_t(y,y')m(dx')m(dy').
$$
Then the process $\overline{Z}_t$ has the generator $A\oplus A$ on $L^2(E,m) \oplus L^2(E,m)$. Furthermore, in view of the heat equations, the transition density of $\overline{Z}_t$ satisfies in some sense
$$
\partial_t\bigg( p_t(x,x')p_t(y,y')\bigg) = \bigg(A_{x'}+A_{y'}\bigg)\bigg( p_t(x,x')p_t(y,y')\bigg)
$$
with $p_0(x,x')p_0(y,y') = \delta_{x}(x')\delta_y(y').$ Where $A_x$ denote the generator act on function with $x$ as variable.
So my guess is that, the Dirichlet form for the process $(X_t,Y_t)_{t \ge 0}$. call it ${\cal E}^2$, is defined via
$$
{\cal E}^2(f,g) = \int_{E\times E} \bigg((A_x+A_y)f(x,y)\bigg) g(x,y)m(dx)m(dy)
$$
where $f(\cdot,y)$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ are in domain of $A$ for all $x,y$ and same for $g$.
